# If cell is not blank go to next sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have created a request form in Excel 2010 that uses multiple sheets, to seperate each request the user puts in. On my first Sheet, "Title Page", I have hyperlinks so the user can jump to a specific Request # (Request 1= sheet 2, Request 2= sheet 3, Request 3= sheet 4 etc). In each of those Request sheets, I have a table set up for the user to input their requests. The start of their data would be entered into cell B6. I would like a way to have a "next blank request" link/formula so the user can click and it will search for the, well, next blank request.

I'd image it would sound something like this:

```
If ('Request 1'!B6) is not blank, go to ('Request 2'!B6).
If ('Request 2!'B6) is not blank, go to ('Request 3'!B6).. etc
If ('Request 4'!B6) is blank, go to ('Request 4'!B6). end.
```

Because this is a table, i am not even sure the cells are truly "blank". Ideally i would like to have this on each request sheet, as well as the Title page. I hope this is not too vague and/or confusing! Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: So you need Excel-VBA code or Formula ?

Answer (score 0):

To find if a cell is blank, you could do a check to see if the cell's value is empty. For example, `If Cells(x, y).Value = "" Then...`. Combine this with a loop going through all the cells in question, and you have a way of finding the next blank cell.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using

> IsEmpty(Cells(x, y).Value)

instead of

> Cells(x, y).Value = ""

Or change it the following if you want to see if something is currently in its default value.

```
Cells(x, y).Value = Empty
```